# ActionBar in Android 1.6

Tags: android

I have this source in my app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setTheme(getHoneycombStyle());
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.ACTION_BAR);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in Honeycomb, Android 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3, but, it doesn't works in android 1.6. Although I have checked the SDK version, the app returns this exception:

```
08-31 18:23:33.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262): java.lang.VerifyError: com.eldan.introducing.activity.IBBaseCompActivity
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2242)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:631)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:317)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:127)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:346)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:850)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1712)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1202)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1987)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1696)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
08-31 18:23:33.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It sounds like the compiler detects the `ActionBar` source in my `onCreate` method, and Android 1.6 doesn't support it. But I'm not very sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot refer to classes or methods from newer versions of Android in code that is loaded into the VM of older versions of Android.

You have two major options:

1. Isolate the `ActionBar` code into a separate utility class and only use that class when you are on Honeycomb, as determined by `android.os.Build`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC) demonstrating making use of `getActionView()` for putting a custom layout into the action bar, that works on Honeycomb and older versions, by isolating the `getActionView()` call in a `HoneycombHelper` class that is only ever used on Honeycomb.
2. Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for your access to the action bar. It will give you the native action bar on Honeycomb and a workalike on older versions of Android.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, and I am using ACtionBarSherlock.. Only crashes on 1.6

Comment: As this question appears as a first when searching for "ActionBar 1.6", I would like to clarify that ActionBarSherlock does not support android 1.6 (API Level 4) any more. Found on YouTube, and in few other places: "You cannot implement ABS on an API level lower than 7 (2.1)."

Comment: @luskan: You are correct. ABS did support 1.6 at the time I wrote the answer. That was back in the 3.x generation of ABS. Now, ABS 4.x only supports API Level 7+.